# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial: 'Heroku Console'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I am working through this tutorial book and have set up my heroku account and git and have successfully pushed pages to heroku. When I enter the command, 'heroku console,' I get the following: 
Nicholass-MacBook-Pro:sample_app nbkincaid$ heroku console
 !    Internal server error

I can't figure out the reason for this, and the heroku logs don't give me much help. Does anyone have a method to try to debug this? Thank you, Nick.

Comment: Check logs, there is too little info you provided.

Comment: the logs don't reflect anything from this command

Comment: does `heroku info` work?

Comment: Hello John, here is what heroku info gave back:Nicholass-MacBook-Pro:sample_app nbkincaid$ heroku info
=== blooming-mist-5381
Addons:        Basic Logging, Shared Database 5MB
Database Size: 72k
Dynos:         1
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:blooming-mist-5381.git
Owner:         nbkincaid@gmail.com
Repo Size:     12M
Slug Size:     10M
Stack:         bamboo-mri-1.9.2
Web URL:       http://blooming-mist-5381.heroku.com/
Workers:       0
Nicholass-MacBook-Pro:sample_app nbkincaid$ ========>>>>>> Seems to me as if its just generic info, thank you for the offering though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is definitely wrong, and from what you've said it doesn't look like you.  I would contact support.

Comment: Sorry Neil, I was a little shorter than I normally am with this question, I just wasn't sure where to draw information from to include. I'll try to be more consistent!

Comment: Thank you, Neil. I've been in contact with the heroku support team about this and they've been helping out.